# "SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'" when loading JSON file for ngx-translate with Karma runner

Tags: json, angular, karma-runner, ngx-translate

I am trying to setup system tests for an Angular app.

It uses the TranslateModule (ngx-translate) like this:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: 'de',
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
      missingTranslationHandler: {
        provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
        useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler,
      },
    }),
```

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

I used a **proxy** in **karma.conf.js** to adapt the request and the file is now found by the TranslateLoader.

Still, when I run the tests with Karma I get an error on the Karma server:

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'
http://localhost:9876/base/src/assets/i18n/de.json?e0ac90c584fb64b071dedb9301cd9342777ed8a2:2
```

The JSON file should be working fine, since it can be viewed in the browser (with clicking on that link) and also it works fine under normal development environments.

There needs to be some sort of preprocessor (or similar) since Karma doesn't recognize the JSON file, I suppose.

Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: Can you post an example of what is inside this json file?

Comment: Is the first `:` in `export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient):` a correct syntax? I don't think parameters should have them without been inside quotes.

Comment: The error in line 2 refers to this:
```{
  "menu": {
```

I strongly believe the JSON file isn't the problem as it is working in all the other places. And I believe the http: HttpClient (as parameter) is a valid TypeScript syntax

Comment: when I use an empty json file (really empty!) then it somehow works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it helped now to set `included: false` in `karma.conf.js` under `files/pattern` where I loaded the JSON file.